# How good are we at closing questions?

Tags: discussion

I'm curious as to how good, bad or indifferent we are are closing questions

- What percentage of questions that enter the close queue end up being closed ?
- What percentage of questions that get closed end up being reopened ?
- How many people voted to close questions.
- How many voted to reopen questions.

What are the numbers that go with those statistics ?

Comment: You'll have to get a SE Employee to answer those. Can say that December 2013 saw the least Questions and Answers ever, and Jan '14 was in the bottom 5. Question closing remained steady at ~1Q/h.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/164049/percentage-of-closed-questions-per-month - looks like Nov 2013 = 7.7%, Dec 2013 = 8.5%, Jan 2014 = 12%, and so far in Feb 2014 = 20%.  Doesn't quite answer your questions, but might still be helpful.

Comment: @TheCleaner: I'm more interested in trying to get a handle of the closed/reopened relationship.

Comment: @Iain - others to look at or possibly fork: http://data.stackexchange.com/serverfault/query/79008/how-many-posts-are-reopened-per-month and http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/75547/closed-reopened-questions

Answer (score -8):

You suck at closing questions. [Very useful and popular ones](https://serverfault.com/questions/191140/best-ssh-program-for-windows) are closed and locked because they are product recommendations.

The motivation is that this type of question would attract spam, which in my experience has never been a problem because those who post good answers generally care enough about their reputation to not post spam, and spam answers get downvoted or deleted. What happens in actuality is that locked questions can't get updates, and the hordes of new users who land on SF via Google searches enjoy antiquated answers, or ones that have become wrong but nobody is able to correct.

Comment: Who "sucks" at closing questions?  Everybody?  Generally, five votes from anybody with sufficient reputation can put a question into hold stsatus ...  not just the SE serverfault site administrators....and then it goes into another queue needing more votes from the community before it is finally closed.  Sometimes the serverfault administrator (who are voted on by all of us) need to address specific questions for specific reasons for the benefit of the serverfault commmunity.

Comment: Oh dear what a whinge which fails to answer my questions entirely too. If you feel strongly that a question is incorrectly closed, you can always ask your own question here on meta to discuss it. Personally I'm not a fan of leaving stuff like that hanging about because it does become outdated.

Comment: -1: questions asking for software recommendations are off-topic, not because they attract spam as you assert, but because they solicit opinion.  Stack Overflow attempts to avoid opinion and the resultant chatter, and focus instead on fact.

Comment: Locked shopping questions which have gone out of date are a whole other issue. Feel free to ask your own question about them.

Comment: "Shopping" questions are off topic in the vast majority of the Stack Exchange sites.